# How to inject separate JS file in directive Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have custom JS file that contents object:

```
var feed = {}
```

Also I have directive.

How to inject this custom JS file, that directive could be read `feed` object inside

Comment: Add `<script src="yourJsFile.js"></script>` in your HTML DOM. Than you will be able to acces `feed`.

Comment: This is enough?

Comment: Yes, due to its a global variable and accessable in your whole application.

Comment: And where in directive may I handle var feed?

Comment: Where ever you want, its global so its accesable in your whole application =)

Comment: If you're using a build system, like Webpack, I'd recommend bundling the script in with the rest of your scripts using the script loader. That way it gets the processing, bundling etc. Otherwise if you're not using a build system, then adding it as the comments say makes it globally accessible. You don't have to inject it, you just use it because the script (and its objects, functions etc) are globally available.